# Solving a Matrix Equation for a Matrix

Tags: matrices

I have a transformation that is determined by the multiplication of several matrices: Transformation = $\mathbf{ABC}$.

I need to find such matrix $\mathbf{K}$ to satisfy equation: 
$\mathbf{ABC} = \mathbf{ACKB}$ .

Comment: uh... if you have $X = Y Z$ do you know how to find Z ?

Comment: How is $A$ relevant to this problem?

Comment: @leonbloy I don't know X.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan - I agree that A is no relevant, I've just posted the whole transformation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $C$ and $B$ are invertible, then this is a very simple matter: just take $K=C^{-1}BCB^{-1}$, which trivially works.

What if either $B$ or $C$ are not invertible? Then it may be impossible to find such a $K$, depending on what $A$, $B$, or $C$ are.

For example, consider the case where they are all $2\times 2$ matrices, and $A$ is to the identity, so that you are simply looking for a $K$ such that $BC=CKB$. Let
$$B = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\0&0\end{array}\right),\qquad C=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\1&1\end{array}\right).$$
Then $BC = B$. But no matrix $K$ can satisfy $CKB=BC$, since $CKB$ will necessarily be of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\*&*
\end{array}\right)\neq B.$$

So if $A$, $B$, and $C$ are certain *specific* matrices, or they have specific properties, you need to specify them.